Preventing Image Compression in Outlook (or any other Office App) for MAC
On Windows it is possible to set Outlook (or any other Office app) to stop compressing images (see image below).

I have searched online and explored the setting but was not able to find a similar feature on Outlook. Is there a solution for this?

I am not sure Outlook do ANY changes on images in mails.
